# How to Document ES6 class members with nested Structures?

Tags: javascript, documentation, ecmascript-6

Is there an accepted way (that is preferably IDE compatible) to document the shape nested members in ES6?

For example

```
class Foo extends React.Components {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.props.bar; // Webstorm for example will think 'bar' is not a member of props
    }
}
```

Is there something we can do to aid the IDE in understanding the expected structure of our class members? Something like:

```
/** @member {string} props.bar **/
```

at the top of the class declaration or constructor

Comment: There is such thing. Typescript.

Comment: I do use that for things ... not an option for all projects that I do not fully own :-(

Comment: Type hinting is one of the reasons why people switch to TS even if type checking provides no real benefits for their projects. I suppose that your best bet is Flow, it supports [commented annotations](http://flowtype.org/blog/2015/02/20/Flow-Comments.html) and got some support from IDEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@property` kinda works, but feels flaky.

```
/**
 * @property {object} props
 * @property {number} props.bar
 */
class Foo extends React.Components {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
}
```

Ugly as hell, but works like clockwork:

```
class Foo extends React.Components {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        /** @type {{foo: {bar: {}}}} */
        this.props = this.props;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this appears to be working. gonna go with approach #1